# Angular: Instagram authorization - access token

Tags: angular, express, oauth, instagram, loopback

So, I am building an app, that would (among other things) provide instagram, twitter, fb and yt live feeds on a specific hashtag

Right now I am working on instagram (first) thinking it would be a piece of cake

- register as dev
- register an app
- get a appId and a secret
- angular http API call to instagram to get access token (using app id and secret)
- angular http API call to instagram getFeed?hashtag=xy (using access token)...

now, obviously, it is not like this...

- so first of, instagram had me register app and client and redirect url
- then I need to make an api call to get a CODE ([link](https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/) ... using my client_id and redirect uri)
- then with this I would go to get ACCESS TOKEN
- and only then I would be able to get to the normal get feed API call

well, I don't mind that extra step to get the CODE.... but... the redirect URL is messing with the flow... I don't know what to do...

In my angular (4 cli) app, user is working normally, that it gets to a profile page.... he would with a tab select a social platform and get the feed populated... now... I don't want the user to be redirected to the app from instagram, twitter, fb and yt... four times.... not even once... I want this to happen behind the scenes with the normal API calls

so if I do in my instagram.service.ts

```
getAccessToken() {
  const api = 'https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/';

  const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
    .set('client_id', clientId)
    .set('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:4200/auth/')
    .set('response_type', 'code');

  return this.http.get<any[]>(api, {params})
  .map((response) => response)
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.error || 'Server error'));
}
```

and call it, in my developer tools I see this
[image]

so the API call was successful, but angular app does not handle my auth path... so it gives 404.... even though in my routes I do have:

```
  {path: 'auth', children: [
    {path: ':instagramtoken', component: MatchesLandingPageComponent},
    {path: '**', component: MatchesLandingPageComponent},
  ] },
```

So my question is, how da hell do I handle this? without any redirects?

.
.
.

I am also using LOOPBACK express server for my backend (to get the data via RESTful API) .... might be a way to do this in there? so I would then just get a 
http://localhost:3000/api/instagram?hashtag=xy ??

Comment: Sir can you tell me which tutorial you to follow for implement instagram?

Answer (score 1):

First a few remarks:

You won't use a client_secret because you are using it in a front end application. I won't be a secret anymore if you'd put it in your javascript code. So in this case you will be using the implicit flow.

It might be useful the use a library for that. [This is a good one.](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login)

> I don't want the user to be redirected to the app from instagram, twitter, fb and yt... four times.... not even once...

I'm sorry, but you will have to. This is the only way the providers know the users autorized your app. This isn't needed before every request because you can store the tokens in you session storage. (A library might do this for you by itself.) This will work for Instagram as their tokens don't expire, but for other this might not be the same.

Now about that 404, it is redirecting to `http://localhost:4200/auth/?code...`. This isn;t the correct url and you probably want it to be `http://localhost:4200/auth?code=...`

So change `.set('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:4200/auth/')` to `.set('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:4200/auth')`.

Comment: I don't want my users to authorize via instagram, I want my APP (as a user) to be authorized... that's the whole point.... is not that a user is logging in to instagram via my app... or logging in to my app via instagram! my users have nothing to do with instagram

Comment: but it looks like I am going to solve it on the backend side with my loopback app - https://strongloop.com/strongblog/using-loopback-to-build-apis-for-apis/

Comment: I understand you want your app te be authorized. But in orded to do that, a user needs to sign in to that app and give access.

Comment: in other words, is not possible otherwise on the front end side... OK